# Web API POST Request returns 500 Error, GET Request returns 200 OK on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I created a web API which runs perfectly on localhost.

After publishing it to Azure

**POST** Request returns 500 Internal Server Error

**GET** Request returns 200 OK

Is there something else required to do in Azure in order to make POST requests accessible and ready to be tested in Postman?

Comment: For me, Web API returning ```405 Method Not Allowed```

Comment: The 500 error is very common when deploying an application.  It can be caused by lots of reasons 1) You are accessing a database and the application cannot access the application from the server account 2) You are using HTTPS and the TLS is failing during the connection 3) The Server doesn't have permissions to access the resources on the server 4) Files may not be installed on server.  These are only some of the reasons for the failure.  It is best to log errors to a file so you can debug or install VS to help find issues.

Comment: I'm not accessing any database, file or resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@W.Gates provided a link that helped me solve my issue

I added the following line to the Program.cs file

**app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();**

I sent the POST Request and saw that the JSON I provided had an error.

After correcting the JSON format, I could successfully send POST Requests.

So by adding that line of code I knew immediately where the error was.